# Understanding server configuration - server has one IP and web site is on another IP

Tags: networking, ip, webserver, wcf

I came across a situation where there is an IIS server with a website on it, and the IP of a web site is different from the server IP. I am a newby whe it comes to networking and would appreciate any insights.

So the server name is `Server1` and website is accessed using `aliasname.sys.domain.com`. I hosted my WCF service on that server and access it using `aliasname.sys.domain.com`. I have noticed that in xml generated by my `wsdl` I have schemaLocation as `Server1.subdomain.domain.com` instead of `aliasname.sys.domain.com`. While I found a workaround and fixed the issue, I am still trying to understand why this was happening in the first place. Also why would there be a need for multiple IP addresses on the same server. Would really appreciate any pointers

Comment: How many IPs on that server? You can have a WebServer with multiple IPs where each IP can be a different site. A more often setup is where a server listens on one IP but hosts different sites depending on the name the request comes in. eg. your servers IP a.b.c.d is configured in DNS with one A record and multiple CNAME records. The name of the server does not have to be the same as the name of the site. If you have any documentation about your server's setup - or organisation design - this might give you a clue why it was setup like you found it.

Comment: @Zina I don't have any documentation on that server. Tyring to figure things out one by one

Comment: Some more guessing from my side then. Are those IPs you mentioned from the same range? Would you share the first two octets of both? It might be one internal and one public IP.